# Is there any PF log parser for FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, logs, firewall

I am runing FreeBSD 8 stable with PF as firewall, I am looking for any tool for parsing PF log's.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

> The log file written by pflogd is in
>   binary format and cannot be read using
>   a text editor. Tcpdump must be used to
>   view the log.
>
> To view the log file:
>
> ```
> # tcpdump -n -e -ttt -r /var/log/pflog
> ```

other useful [info here](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/logging.html)

Comment: I am looking for some thing built with perl or C, some thing give statics, show time, and highlight issues(for scanning for example), with structured format like tables.

Answer (score 0):

How about Splunk? 
It processes any machine data and gives ability to do all sorts of acrobatics with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a very useful tool for pf real-time information and limited statistics: [`sysutils/pftop`](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/pftop/)

As the name already suggests, it works much like the `top` utility.